# create and edit objects in Core Data - 3 different approach by some of most famous books

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, parameter-passing

i've been reading few posts about saving with core data. I noticed that most of the time everyone forgot to consider that the hardest part is the edit of objects rather than the creation.

I read 3 different books about core data, i will share with you all the methods those books use. and i would be curious to know which approach you would apply for your own application.

### **Core Data iOS Essentials - Packt Publishing**

theres a RootVC, an AddCustomerVC and a EditCustomerVC. we want to create or edit a Customer

  
1) the user click the ADD button in the RootVC
2) the add button method create an object and sets it as the Object *myobject variable of the DetailVC

```
-(IBAction) addCustomer { 
    AddCustomerVC *addVC = [AddCustomerVC alloc]init];
    addVC.customer = (Customer *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    addVC.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addVC animated:YES];
}
```

3) the detailVC sets the Customer instance attributes and calls the delegate method

```
-(IBAction) save {
    customer.name = newName.text;
    customer.surname = newSurname.text;
    [delegate addVC:self selectedSave:YES];
}
```

4) if the user press Cancel in the addVC the actions calls the delegate method

```
-(IBAction) cancel {
    [delegate addVC:self selectedSave:NO];
}
```

5) the RootVC delegate implementation check if the user saved and save the context

```
-(void) addVC:(UIViewController *)controller selectedSave:(BOOL)save {
    if(!save) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:controller.customer];
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if( ! [self.managedObjectContext save:&error] ) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

1 edit) the user click on the cell and it calls the method for the cell selection where it create a Customer with the selected value and open the EditVC

```
-(void)tablewView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    EditCustomerVC editVC = [[EditCustomerVC alloc]init];
    Customer *selectedCustomer = (Customer *) [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    editVC.customer = selectedCustomer;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:editVC animated:YES];
}
```

2 edit) the user press the save button, sets the values of the customer and it calls the delegate

```
-(IBAction) save {
    customer.name = name.text;
    customer.surname = surname.text;
    [delegate editVC:self selectedSave:YES];
}
```

3b)if the user press cancel it calls the delegate

```
-(IBAction) cancel {
    [delegate editVC:self selectedSave:NO];
}
```

4b) the delegate save the edited object

```
.(void)editVC:(UIViewController *)controller selectedSave:(BOOL)save {
    if(save) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if( ! [self.managedObjectContext save:&error] ) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

### **Pro Core Data for iOS - Apress**

We have a MasterVC and a TeamVC where we can create and edit a Team

  
1) when the user click the ADD button it calls the showTeamVC passing it the MasterVC and a team

```
-(void)showTeamVC {
    TeamVC *teamVC = [[TeamVC alloc]initWithController:self andTeam:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:teamVC animated:YES];
}
```

2) the init of the TeamVC sets the passed value as its iVar

```
-(id)initWithController:(UIViewController *)controller andTeam:(Team *)team {
    self.controller = controller;
    self.team = team;
}
```

3) the viewDidLoad sets the fields of the view with the value that he got from the object
4) when the user press cancel the controller just gets dismissed
5) when the user click save it calls the save action that check if team is nil ( to see if you passed a team or not, so if you are adding or editing ) and calls the save or insert method of the master controller

```
-(IBAction)save {
    if ( team != nil ){
        team.name = nameTextField.text;
        team.colors = colorsTextField.text;
        [controller saveContext];
    } else {
        [controller insertTeamWithName: nameTextField.text andColors:colorsTextField.text];
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

6) if you saved a new team it will be called the insertTeamWithName:andColors method in the MasterVC

```
-(void)insertTeamWithName:(NSString *)name andColors:(NSString *)colors {
    NSManagedObjectContext *contextx = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    Team *newTeam = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Team" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [self saveContext];
}
```

7) if you edited a team it will be called the saveContext method in the MasterVC

```
-(void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectcontext];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ( ! [context save:&error] ) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
}
```

### **Core Data for iOS - core framework series**

this is considered one of the best book for core data, even if is quite outdated 
this has a total different approach

we have a RootVC and a PersonEditorVC we can add and edit Person

1) when the rootVC button add is pressed it calls the setCurrentPerson:nil method on the PersonEditorVC and open that view

```
- (void)addNewPerson {
    [self.personEditorViewController setCurrentPerson:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.personEditorViewController animated:YES];
}
```

2) the PersonEditorVC method setCurrentPerson gets called by the previous method. if person is nil it calls the Person initializer, if person is not nil it gets its objectID

```
- (void)setCurrentPerson:(AWPerson *)aPerson {
    if( !aPerson )
    {
        self.title = @"Add person";
        aPerson = [AWPerson 
                   personInManagedObjectContext:self.editingContext];
    }
    else if( [aPerson managedObjectContext] != self.editingContext ) {
        self.title = @"Edit person";

        aPerson = (id)[self.editingContext 
                       objectWithID:[aPerson objectID]];
    }

    if( currentPerson != aPerson ) {
        [currentPerson release];
        currentPerson = [aPerson retain];
    }
}
```

3) the PersonEditorVC opens n set its textfield if the person is not nil, then gets the edited value from the textfield at each textFieldShouldReturn

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if( textField == self.firstNameTextField )
        [self.currentPerson setFirstName:textField.text];
    else if( textField == self.lastNameTextField )
        [self.currentPerson setLastName:textField.text];

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

4) when the user press cancel, it just goes back to the old controller, if he press save, it just save the context

```
- (IBAction)savePerson:(id)sender {
    NSError *anyError = nil;
    BOOL success = [[currentPerson managedObjectContext] 
                    save:&anyError];
    if( !success ) {
        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                   initWithTitle:@"Couldn't save this person"
                                   message:[anyError localizedDescription] 
                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [errorAlert show];
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

5) it's important to note the initializer that its written in the auto generated model class

```
+ (id)personInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc {
    return [NSEntityDescription 
            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
            inManagedObjectContext:moc];
}
```

1 edit) if the user wants to edit a person and click on the person row in the table it gets called the tableview method where it just calls the setCurrentPerson, with a person

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AWPerson *selectedPerson = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self.personEditorViewController setCurrentPerson:selectedPerson];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.personEditorViewController animated:YES];
}
```

### conclusions

here we have 3 totally different approach, from 3 of best books on Core Data.

**Which is your fav approach? do you use a different one? why do you like one more than the other?**

personally i find the last one to be the best, even if it can be less easier to code, it's surely the best syntax, more reusable and so on.
but for a small app i would probably use the first one.

Comment: +1 for your research effort, but voting to close as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: ty for the plus but it's not only for opinions, it's meant to better understand the use of those concepts, considering that lately i read many post where there is a lot of confusion around that :) imho would be good if people would partecipate saying their approach :)

Comment: imho the easier the better. i like the first book the most, that's the way i'd do.